# I'm trying to execute different fetch based on data type but I'm always getting same data

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to execute different fetch based on data type but I'm always getting same data. So here is the code where I'm fetching data:

```
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      if (widget.vrstaDokumenta == "Moji zadaci") {
        var dokumenti =
            await _dokumentiService!.getForApprovalByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
      }
      if (widget.vrstaDokumenta == "Moji dokumenti") {
        var dokumenti =
            await _dokumentiService!.getMojiDokumentiByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
      }
      var dokumenti =
          await _dokumentiService!.getSharedDocumentsByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);

      setState(() {
        _dokumenti = dokumenti;
        _dokumentiSearch = dokumenti;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
```

I'm always getting this code executed:

```
var dokumenti =
          await _dokumentiService!.getSharedDocumentsByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
```

Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

write it like this and see what happens:

```
if (widget.vrstaDokumenta == "Moji zadaci") {
        var dokumenti =
            await _dokumentiService!.getForApprovalByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
      }
    else if (widget.vrstaDokumenta == "Moji dokumenti") {
        var dokumenti =
            await _dokumentiService!.getMojiDokumentiByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
      }else{
var dokumenti =
          await _dokumentiService!.getSharedDocumentsByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
}
```

Comment: If I do it like that i get error in setState undefined name dokumenti

Answer (score 1):

Basically what happens is that your setting the value of dokumenti always twice, first you set the right value but then you overwrite it by calling _dokumentiService.getSharedDocumentsByType(). Consider wrapping this in a condition as well.

However using switch/case would be suited best for what you are trying to do.

```
switch(widget.vrstaDokumenta) {
    case "Moji zadaci":
      var dokumenti =
                await _dokumentiService!.getForApprovalByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
    case: "Moji Dokumenti":
      var dokumenti =
                await _dokumentiService!.getMojiDokumentiByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
    default: 
      var dokumenti =
              await _dokumentiService!.getSharedDocumentsByType(widget.tipId ?? 0); 
}
```

Consider wrapping the switch case statement inside a seperate function to make it even cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I made it like this and it's working now:

```
 if (widget.vrstaDokumenta == "Moji zadaci") {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
        var dokumenti =
            await _dokumentiService!.getForApprovalByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
        setState(() {
          _dokumenti = dokumenti;
          _dokumentiSearch = dokumenti;
          isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    if (widget.vrstaDokumenta == "Moji dokumenti") {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
        var dokumenti =
            await _dokumentiService!.getMojiDokumentiByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
        setState(() {
          _dokumenti = dokumenti;
          _dokumentiSearch = dokumenti;
          isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    if (widget.vrstaDokumenta == "Podijeljeni") {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      var dokumenti =
          await _dokumentiService!.getSharedDocumentsByType(widget.tipId ?? 0);
      setState(() {
        _dokumenti = dokumenti;
        _dokumentiSearch = dokumenti;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
    }
```